# Dot Net Core using NLog creates log file, but never logs anything

Tags: c#, .net-core, nlog

I've tried various changes based on what other people were doing, right now it's almost exactly like the tutorial shows.

I can see it create it's internal log, then it creates my log file with the init main, then nothing after that gets logged.

nlog.config

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Info"
      internalLogFile="c:\temp\internal-nlog.txt">

  <!-- enable asp.net core layout renderers -->
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
  </extensions>

  <!-- the targets to write to -->
  <targets>
    <!-- write logs to file  -->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="allfile" fileName="c:\logs\nlog-all-${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}" />
  </targets>

  <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
  <rules>
    <!--All logs, including from Microsoft-->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="allfile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Program.cs

```
   public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // NLog: setup the logger first to catch all errors
        var logger = NLog.Web.NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();
        try
        {
            logger.Debug("init main");
            //BuildWebHost(args).Build().Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //NLog: catch setup errors
            logger.Error(ex, "Stopped program because of exception");
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Ensure to flush and stop internal timers/threads before application-exit (Avoid segmentation fault on Linux)
            NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
        }

        var webHost = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
                config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                      .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
                config.AddEnvironmentVariables();

                //Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().MinimumLevel.Error().WriteTo.RollingFile(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "logs/{Date}.txt")).CreateLogger();
            })
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
                logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
                logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
            })
            .UseNLog()
            .Build();

        webHost.Run();
    }
```

And here's an example of how I'm using it in a controller

```
public class AuthController : BaseController
{
    private readonly ILogger<AuthController> _logger;

    public AuthController(CoordinaireDbContext context, ILogger<AuthController> logger, AuthService Auth) : base(context, Auth)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AuthPost(LoginModel model)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("test log");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code initializes NLog then calls `NLog.LogManager.Shutdown()` and then launches the WebHost.

Try this instead:

```
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
        // NLog: setup the logger first to catch all errors
        var logger = NLog.Web.NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();
        try
        {
            logger.Debug("init main");
            BuildWebHost(args).Build().Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //NLog: catch setup errors
            logger.Error(ex, "Stopped program because of exception");
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Ensure to flush and stop internal timers/threads before application-exit (Avoid segmentation fault on Linux)
            NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
        }
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder BuildWebHost(string[] args)
    {
            var webHost = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                {
                    var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
                    config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                          .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
                    config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
                })
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    logging.ClearProviders();
                    logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
                })
                .UseNLog();
        return webHost;
    };
```